# selecting certain users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a zombie survival app, and I'm trying to select all my users marked "alive" where :alive is a boolean.
I was writing a private method in my users controller but can't get the ruby right, does anyone have a pointer?

```
 def get_alive
   @holder = (User.map {|user| user})
   @user = @holder.each {|i| if i.alive @user << i}
 end
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a scope to find all alive users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :alive, where(:alive => true)
  # ... the rest of your model ...
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
@alive_users = User.alive
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure why I got a down vote on this.  If gathering alive users is going to be a common occurrence throughout the app, it's best to create a scope for it.

Comment: @Adam the advantage of using a scope is that you can just type `.alive` throughout your code -- without having to repeat the whole 'where' statement over and over..

Comment: The benefits become more evident when you have somewhat complex queries that have to be repeated throughout the application.  This example was somewhat trivial, but it's best to start thinking DRY'ly from the beginning.  Another benefit of using scopes is the chaining capability.  Let's say you had `scope :in_danger, where("health <= ?", 20)`.  Then you could grab all of the alive, in danger users with `User.alive.in_danger`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give a bit more details what "holder" is supposed to be... and why you are comparing against 'i'

otherwise:

```
User.where(:alive => true)
```

it's a good idea to wrap this in a scope as in Sean Hill's answer

Comment: @holder was just a random instance variable I made up to hold the entire list

Comment: you don't need it.   you can either iterate over the results of the above selection with `.each` , or you can append `.all` to get the complete list.

Answer (score 1):

You could just select those users directly if `User` is active record:

```
User.where(:alive => true)
```

Or filter for just those users:

```
User.all.filter(&:alive)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use this syntax in where query

```
User.where(alive: true)
```

Or use select over array of object. But select is slow

```
User.all.select{ |user| user.alive == true}
```